# duplicity with ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, bandwidth, duplicity

I'm relatively new to posting here, so please pardon infelicities.

I'm trying to set up a duplicity backup through a 2-step ssh tunnel that I set up in config with one alias - call that alias "faraway". So for example  `ssh faraway` works fine (with the right key in `ssh-agent`). But then when I try

```
duplicity local-dir sftp://faraway//remote-dir/
```

I get

```
BackendException: ssh connection to [second-remote-server] failed: timed out
```

I read somewhere that duplicity reinvents `ssh` in python or something, so I'm guessing that has to do with the problem, but I don't know to fix it.

*Bonus questions*: I'd really like to be able to throttle the bandwidth on this connection. Also, if there are any extra pitfalls to doing this in `cron`, please warn me. (I have already learned some of the `cron` pitfalls - I have duplicity working okay with `ssh-agent` in `cron` using `sshfs` instead, but I can't easily throttle that without learning `tc` it seems.)

Answer (score 1):

[Manual page](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) explains the how you can modify this behavior, so it will use something different than `paramiko`:

> SCP/SFTP access
>
> `scp://..` or
>
> `sftp://user[:password]@other.host[:port]/[relative|/absolute]_path`
>
> defaults are `paramiko+scp://` and `paramiko+sftp://`
>     alternatively try `pexpect+scp://`, `pexpect+sftp://`, `lftp+sftp://`
>     See also `--ssh-askpass`, `--ssh-options` and *A NOTE ON SSH BACKENDS**.

You should be able to use

```
duplicity local-dir pexpect+sftp://faraway//remote-dir/
```

which should fall back to the `ssh` backend itself.

> I'd really like to be able to throttle the bandwidth on this connection.

Again, manual page for `sftp` speaks about limitation of the transfer speeds:

> `-l limit`
>
> Limits the used bandwidth, specified in Kbit/s.

You can specify that using `--ssh-options` to pass it to `duplicity`:

```
duplicity --ssh-options="-l 100" local-dir pexpect+sftp://faraway//remote-dir/
```

Comment: Thanks! I *did* read the `man` page, and even the section on ssh backends - but obviously not carefully enough. I assumed `pexpect` was some fancy variation on `paramiko` rather than the default `ssh`. (I did know how to throttle regular `ssh`, but not `paramiko`'s version.

Comment: It's still not working though - maybe `pexpect` doesn't read `ssh`'s config file?

Comment: Actually it works fine in the CLI once I figured out my `duplicity` version of wants `--ssh-backend pexpect` rather than `pexpect+sftp` in the url. *But* it does *not* work in `cron` - though as I say I had it reading the `ssh` agent info well enough for `sshfs` before.

Comment: Oops again. Just a typo in the `cron` script. All working now. Thanks again. I'll try more strategies before multi-commenting next time.

Comment: pexect (https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is the most well known Python module for implementing "expect" like features (TCL/expect).  It enables one to automate interactions with pseudo-terminal devices.